# Transparent Object hides other transparent Objects (alphaTest don't works and depthWrite = false causes some trouble)

Tags: three.js, webgl, transparency

I currently have a problem with transparency. As you can see in the pictures, the non transparent objects behind the transparent object are shown. But the `backside`of the other transparent object is not shown, I set `material.side = THREE.DoubleSide`.

It is visible, when I set `material.depthWrite = false`, but then the visible glitch happens, you can see in the second picture.

I use `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial` and the newest Version of `Three.js`.
Here are the values for the material you can see in the picture

```
material.color.setHex(0x9ed7f5);
material.emissive.setHex(0x062f61);
material.transparent = true;
material.opacity = 0.5;
material.needsUpdate = true;
material.reflectivity = 0.8;
material.envMap = textureCube;
material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
material.roughness = 0.2;
material.metalness = 1;
depthWrite = true;
```

[image]

```
depthwrite = false;
```

[image]

Here how it should look, only works if object behind is NOT transparent
[image]

It seems like from the other side I can see the transparent object behind.
[image]

Just to complete my confusion about this problem I have to post another picture. Here you can see picture (1) just from the other side (scene rotated by 180°) as you can see those view is different as there is an object missing in the back (also a transparent one) which is shown in the other view. All of these objects have the exact same material!

[image]

The envMap `textureCube` is created as follows

```
textureCube = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load(urls);
textureCube.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
var shader = THREE.ShaderLib["cube"];
shader.uniforms["tCube"].value = textureCube;
var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader
    , vertexShader: shader.vertexShader
    , uniforms: shader.uniforms
    , depthWrite: false
    , side: THREE.BackSide
});
var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1500, 1500, 1500), shaderMaterial);
scene.add(skyBox);
```

Comment: do you have a fiddle?

Comment: no :/ but maybe I need to start using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't quite make out your issue from your pictures but can you tell me if this is the same thing?

Go to threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshStandardMaterial, in the live example set ambient to white, turn on transparent in the material and set opacity to about 0.7.

Can you see the way that the transparent part of the torus in the foreground occludes other parts when they go behind it? It might take a while but if you watch it as it rotates you should see what I mean.

Unfortunately this is a WebGL limitation, not anything that can be fixed by three.js for the time being.

Comment: Ok, yeah that's exactly what my problem is. Thank you for this answer, now I know it's not caused by a programming mistake of me.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a transparent object, try setting `premultipliedAlpha` to `true`, and that could fix the problem:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 'color', transparent: true,opacity:0.5,premultipliedAlpha: true} );
```

Comment: quite a old problem I just got back to, will not help so far :/

Comment: See if setting `premultipliedAlpha` to `true` workes

Comment: Does not work, just have tried it. I just figured out that from the other side, you can see the other transparent object (see new picture in post). Maybe there is a problem with my 3D-Object, cause the one object is shown through the transparent object and the other not?

Comment: Is it because of the `envMap` on your object?

Comment: I do not know, the envMap is a cube around my scene created like I edited in my post above. I am not that experienced in all those things, learned it by my self and some books, but it is my first bigger project.

Answer (score 0):

In 2019 this is still a top search result for this problem. I found a solution that worked for me (not sure why since this apparently is a weird WebGL problem according to some sources).

After the scene is set up with all transparent objects in it, set the hidden object's material's transparent property to false. Can't say this will work for everyone, but it worked for me. Here's proof:

[image]

The transparent green box is showing up behind the transparent white shapes. It's even possible to change the green box's opacity despite the transparent property being set to false.